# Should I use the same wallet address everywhere, or different addresses?

Tags: wallets

I'm fairly new to Ethereum and I'm interested in learning about standard practice. I currently have three wallet apps I use for Ethereum:

- The official Ethereum Wallet for macOS
- MetaMask for Chrome
- Cipher Browser for iOS

Is it typical when using multiple clients to use separate wallet addresses for each client? Should I try to use the same address for all three clients? What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO it will depend on your usecase. You should use different addresses if you don't want that other are able to correlate your transactions. Moreover, it also depends on the sum at stake. For instance, I wouldn't be comfortable having a larger sum in a browser plugin like MetaMask.

Answer (score 0):

It really comes down to personal preference. If you want to access a specific contract from different devices, you could use the same wallet on multiple clients, but most people don`t. I personally try to use as many different wallets as possible. Every contract I deploy has a different owner.

I have several wallets:

- One *cold* wallet, mostly for ETH/token storage which I almost never open (Ethereum Wallet)
- Several other wallets for management of different contracts (Ethereum Wallet)
- One for dApps (MetaMask)
- One on my phone to pay in real life (has never happened so far...)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using 1 or 2 wallets metamask and some hardware wallet

Answer (score 0):

because of Etherscan labeling, I suggest you use a new address everytime you deploy a new smart contract. otherwise people can easily track what you did